# Pushforward of quasi-coherent sheaves to quotient stack for finite group action?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, modules, derived-functors, algebraic-stacks

Let $R$ be a ring and $G$ be a finite group. 
Assume there is a $G$ action on $\operatorname{Spec} R$. For example, the group $\{\pm1\}$ acts on $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ by $(-1) z = -z$. 
let $\pi : \operatorname{Spec} R \longrightarrow (\operatorname{Spec} R) /G$ be the canonical projection map to the quotient stack.

We can identify $\operatorname{QCoh} (\operatorname{Spec} R)$ with $R$-module and $\operatorname{QCoh} ( (\operatorname{Spec} R) /G)$
with $G$-equivariant $R$-module. 
Under this identification, the pullback $\pi^\ast$ is just the forgetful functor from $G$-equivariant $R$-module to $R$-module. My question is what is $\pi_\ast$ in this case?

Answers or reference are both welcome. The definition I know for this pushforward is from D. Gaitsgory and N. Rozenblyum's book which is not very computational.

Answer (score 1):

It is the right adjoint to the forgetful functor. You might call this the "co-free representation" or the "co-induced representation from the trivial group" (suitably adjusted to the case where $G$ acts non-trivially on $R$) or something like that.

In case $G$ is finite and you think of "$G$-equivariant $R$-modules" in terms of some sort of twisted (noncommutative) group algebra $R[G]$, the right (respectively, left) adjoint to the forgetful functor should look like $\text{Hom}_R(R[G], -)$ (respectively, $R[G] \otimes_R -$). A more "stacky" description would be to look at the Cartesian square below, and try to establish that the base-change morphism is an isomorphism—identifying the underlying $R$-module with$$r_* p_1^* M \cong \mathcal{O}_{X \times G} \otimes_R M,$$and so forth.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X \times G @> r >> X \\
@V p_1 VV     @VV \pi V \\
X @>> \pi > X/G
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: Is $R[G]$ the ring with elements being formal sums of $r \chi^g$ where $r \in R$, $g \in G$ and multiplication being $r \chi^g \cdot s \chi^h = r g(s) \chi^{gh}$?